# Why is Janmashtami an important festival in Hinduism?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

As per my interpretation of the message of the Bhagwad Geeta, the soul is eternal. The birth and death of the body are incidental and material. If this applies for mortals, then why does the birth of a deity considered a special occasion? Shouldn't it be considered an ordinary event?

Comment: good question. The deity is a symbol. He is like a quick shortcut to the God who dwells within us. The reason the deity is special is because the deity thinks, acts and behaves in similar ways to human beings, but at the same time expresses super human gifts. Thus celebrating the birthday is yet another way of giving a human like character to that Indescribable God. By thinking of Him and celebrating His birthday, the presence of a person called God impermeates into our everyday life and takes us closer to the Truth. sir

Comment: U r also eternal. So y celebrate bday?☺ why celbrate bday of loved once? Because its a way of showing that we love nd care.its Tym to contemplate on relation v share with Krishna, to think of His message. Also appearance of god in tbis world isn't an ordinary event.his appearance also is not material. Its transcendental.

Comment: May be because Krishna & Rama are considered most significant Avatars of Vishnu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in your question itself

*"The birth and death of the body are incidental and material. If this applies to mortals.."*

Yes, it applies to mortals.

*"..then why does the birth of a deity considered a special occasion?*

Because it does not apply to deities.

Krishna says so himself in [BG 4.9](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-4-9/):

> जन्म कर्म च मे दिव्यमेवं यो वेत्ति तत्त्वतः।
>
> त्यक्त्वा देहं पुनर्जन्म नैति मामेति सोऽर्जुन ।।
>
> janma karma ca me divyam evaḿ yo vetti tattvataḥ
>   tyaktvā dehaḿ punar janma naiti mām eti so arjuna

My birth and deeds are divine. One who knows this, leaves his body, is not born again and attains me Arjuna.

Bhagavan is celebrated as Aja and Vija - He is the unborn, yet he takes birth. Both God and soul are 'unborn' in the sense that they are not created by anyone. But souls are born in the sense that they take birth due to past karma. God is born in the sense that he takes birth due to karuna (pity), but unborn in the sense that he is unaffected by past karma, and is born of his own free will.

The reason Krishna is born is to prevent us from being born again. But being adamant, we want to enjoy & suffer in this playground of samsara.

We celebrate Janmashtami to remind ourselves that Krishna is waiting for us to join him.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question

> Why is Janmashtami an important festival in Hinduism?

Krishna is associated with absolute joy or bliss. Hence, it serves as a reminder for us to move towards bliss and also to spread joy in the society:

> Janmashtami is the day when we celebrate the birth of Lord Krishna.
>   Lord Krishna signifies Ananda (bliss, pure happiness). We express any
>   happiness by celebration. So Janmashtami is celebrating the birth of
>   Bliss. It is the day when that (divine) joy became manifest. Actually,
>   it is not right to use the word ‘birth’ here. Lord Krishna was never
>   born. That (divine) joy was always present, but it is on this day that
>   it became manifest and evident (in the form of Lord Krishna). So where
>   should you look for Lord Krishna? Everywhere! Lord Krishna says – ‘One
>   who sees Me everywhere, in everyone, and sees everyone in Me is truly
>   intelligent’. Now, no one wants to be foolish in this world. Everyone
>   wants to be intelligent. So, one who recognizes the Parmatma (Supreme
>   soul or all-pervading one Consciousness) as that Anand-tattva (the
>   element of Bliss) that is manifest throughout Creation is truly
>   intelligent. Everything has emerged from that Anand-tattva. This is
>   the special message of Janmashtami. What does one need for this? You
>   need to be innocent at heart; you should have that child-like
>   innocence. It is said – ‘Bhole bhaav miley Raghurai’ (One attains the
>   Lord through the innocence and purity of feelings).
>
> Today’s knowledge is this: It’s time to seriously enjoy and celebrate!
>   (Laughter) You can realize Lord Krishna only through deep rest. You
>   cannot realize Lord Krishna through your struggle and efforts. And
>   when can you get that deep rest? Deep rest happens when your mind is
>   not restless and entangled with feverish desires; when it is not
>   caught up in cravings and aversions. It is in those moments of deep
>   rest that one witnesses the birth of Lord Krishna (here meaning divine
>   bliss)...

Excerpts from an article by Sri Sri Ravi Shankar: http://www.artofliving.org/wisdom/sri-sri-message-janmashtami

Comment: I downvoted because the answer does not address my question.

Comment: @Ketan : Ohhk, I thought its in sync with the title question. Maybe, not in sync with the in-line questions. Would you like me to remove it? :)